# Why sort function in Go and C++ is different? And I can't get the right results in Go

Tags: c++, sorting, go

I want to sort a slice named `nums` while not disrupting the original order.
So I use `inds` to record the index of `nums` and sort `inds`:

```
vector<int> nums = {1,3,2,1,1,1};
vector<int> inds = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
sort(inds.begin(), inds.end(), 
    [nums](int i, int j) -> bool
{ 
    return nums[i] > nums[j]; 
});

for(int i : inds) {
    cout << i;
}
```

The `inds` is `120345` after sort. While in Go, I test:

```
nums := []int{1,3,2,1,1,1}
inds := []int{0,1,2,3,4,5}

sort.Slice(inds, func(i, j int) bool {
    return nums[i] > nums[j]
})

fmt.Println(inds)
```

And The `inds` is `[1 0 2 3 4 5]` after sort, which is different from the result of C++ and what I expected.
Why Go can't sort `inds` well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  anonymous function arguments `i` and `j` are indices in `inds`, but the program uses the arguments as indices in `nums`.

Fix by using `inds` to translate the index values to `nums`:

```
sort.Slice(inds, func(i, j int) bool {
    return nums[inds[i]] > nums[inds[j]]
})
```